# Power query, powerpivot, dashboard

Tags: excel, relationship, powerquery, powerpivot

I am working on a dashboard where I need to connect multiple Excel sheets from different sources. I need to create relationships between the tables but i am not sure as to how call out those relationships effectively .  for eg takingh example of these three tables:

| City_map |
| --- |
| City_id |
| city_Name |

---

| City Details |
| --- |
| order_id |
| City_id |
| Restaurant_id |

---

| Orders |
| --- |
| DATE |
| order_id |
| Revenue |

And so on

I need to create relationships as to effectively find which cities(names of cities) in table **City_map** has generated how much revenue from **orders** table but i am  only able to create relationship betweeen **city Details** & **Orders** table because it has matching **order_id** column and by trying to summarize city_names into power pivots to find the revenue for each city, excel is asking me to define new relationships. Please help me out on how to effectively bring all the data together from each table accurately.

I tried building the following relationship
[image: Relationship for my dashboard]

But was unable to connect between **City_map** or **Restaurant_id map** or **Customer_details** with **Orders** table and i am unable to create a relationship between them do to absence of common column.

Comment: You relate city_map to city_details using City_Id, and city_details to Orders using Order_id. You cannot, and do not need to, relate city_map directly to orders.

Comment: You should merge tables "City Details"  and "Customer Details" into table "Order details", and get rid of them - they make no sense.

Comment: You should really familiarize yourself w/ ["star schema"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema). Other than that, second what @RADO said.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge City_map to City Details by using lookupvalue then create relationship between City Details and Order Details